# Modeling Planet Help

Tags: modeling

so im about eight and a half minutes into this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTq9sLQOiVs

and something isnt working properly. i have followed every step but this happens: [image]

ive refollowed the steps, can anyone give me a fix or something?

Comment: @BrandonAndrews for questions like this it helps to know what you've tried and what you are trying to accomplish. A blend file and pictures of the  relevant settings might make it easier for someone to help you.